# Which of them / Which one of them / Who among them

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do these sentences have absolutely the same meaning, or does the word "one" change something? Does it just emphasize that the speaking is about one certain person?

> **Which of them** is your husband?
>
> **Which one of them** is your husband?

P.S. What about a question "**Who among them** is your husband?"? Is it idiomatic?

Comment: The first two are identical in meaning. "Who among them" is not idiomatic. It sounds to me like some great power talking, like The Wizard of Oz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they have the same meaning - also "Which one is your husband?"

**Who among them** is not very idiomatic for identifying an individual. You might use it for asking whether something applies to any member(s) of a group.

> Who among them has been vaccinated?